# Algorithm to find whether a number X is an arbitrary power

Tags: algorithm

I basically need to have a function that finds that X is the result of a^b, and display a and b but I cannot use any available methods from math libraries.

Comment: So, what have you researched and found so far?

Comment: I know how to recursively find if X is a perfect square and I know that the algorithm will have a complexity of log^3, but I'm stuck as to how it should be implemented in code

Comment: All numbers are of the form `a^b` for some `a` and `b`. What unstated assumptions are you making? I can guess, but specification-guessing is a potential source of bugs.

Comment: That there should exist integers a and b > 1 that a^b is N, so for example if I enter 8, the function should give me 2, and 3, since 2^3 is 8.

Comment: this page have already an answer for you, http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-number-can-be-expressed-as-xy-x-raised-to-power-y/

Comment: @JohnnyWiller yes that page provides an exponential time solution, but there is a polynomial time solution (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Naive solution (pseudocode), looping over `a` (this is exponential time):

```
for (a = 2; a <= sqrt(X); ++a) {
    b = round ( log ( X ) / log( a ) )
    if (a^b == X) {
         output solution
         exit
    }
}
output no solution found
```

Better solution (pseudocode), looping over `b` (this is polynomial time):

```
for (b = 2; b <= log(X)/log(2); ++b) {
    a = round ( exp ( log(X)/b ) )
    if (a^b == X) {
         output solution
         exit
    }
}
output no solution found
```

Better solution in Python:

```
import math

def inv_power(x):
    upper_limit = math.log(x)/math.log(2)
    b = 2
    while b <= upper_limit:
        a = int(round( math.exp ( math.log(x)/b ) ) )
        if a**b == x:
            return a,b
        b = b + 1
    return None
```

Nice question.  I'm disappointed so many people down voted it.

Comment: I think the down-votes are simply for showing a lack of research. OP has simply stated the question and not shown any effort(s) to find a solution. I don't believe the down-votes reflect the quality of the core question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume integers (from comments) so without brute force I would try this:

1. **use sieve of Eratosthenes `O(X.log(log(X)))`**

   Up  to `sqrt(X)` or half bits of `X` number `1<<(bits(X)>>1)` to find primes you will be needing for this.
2. **scan all found primes `p(i)` and check how many times you can divide `X` with it. `m=~X/ln(X); O(m)`**

   Remember the number of divisions as `n`. If `n<=1`then ignore this prime `p(i)` and continue with next `p(i+1)`. If `n>1` then add the prime `p(i)` and its `n` to some list;
3. **sort the `list` by `n` descending `O(m.log(m))`**
4. **now scan the `list` for solutions `q<=m; O(q^2)`**

   so for each entry in `list` divide `X'=X/list[j].p^list[j].n` and now check `X'` the same way (using only entries with the same `n`). If you got `X'=1` then stop the check and output your found result (power is used `n` and `root` is multiplication of all used primes). You need to check all the combinations of primes with same `n` so recursion is the way. If no combination of entries with the same `n` found with resulting in `X'=1` then move to entries with different
   `n` with starting from `X` again.

The recursion could look like this:

```cpp
    bool check(int X,int n,int j,int &a)
     {
     int i,x;
     for (;(list[j].n==n)&&(j<list.size);j++) // scan all primes with the same `n`
      {
      for (x=X,i=0;i<n;i++) x/=list[j].p;     // x=X/p^n
      if (x==1) { a*=list[j].p; return true; }// stop you hit the result
      if (check(x,n,j+1,a)) return true;      // recursion
      }
     return false;
     }
```

Where `X` is the number to check, `n` is actually checked power, `j` is starting entry in found list (no need to test previous entries as they have been already checked) and `a` is the base for power.If solution found returns true else false.

So now you just check all found powers with it and output/stop first found solution:

```cpp
    int a,n,j; 
    for (j=0,n=list[j].n;j<list.size;)
     {
     a=1; if (check(X,n,j,a)) return solution X=a^n;// check power `n`
     while ((n==list[i].n)&&(j<list.size)) i++;     // find next power
     }
    return no solution found;
```

You can combine some of these steps together especially **#1,#2** (even avoid recursion). If you need floating or fixed point approach or want to add some additional ideas for integers see and the sub-link too:

- [How to calculate Python float-number-th root of float number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34223324/2521214)

Here very similar **Q/A** with C++ solution covering your questio:

- [Finding whether a number has P^Q form or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33075747/2521214)