# [InterviewBit]Power Of Two Integers

Tags: algorithm, recursion

this is the question:
Given a positive integer which fits in a 32 bit signed integer, find if it can be expressed as A^P where P > 1 and A > 0. A and P both should be integers.

I know that I can solve it using brute-force method; however, I am wondering if I could solve it in a better way, or can I solve it using recursion technique? 
Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: Why "power of **two**"?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth He meant "(power of) (two integers)"

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Ohhhh...

Comment: @Maharaj My biggest concern is that if this problem can be solved using recursion?

Comment: Can you include some pseudocode that you tried to arrive at  solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding whether a number has P^Q form or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066757/finding-whether-a-number-has-pq-form-or-not)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to convert to `double`, and use math to obtain fractional powers of `1/2`, `1/3`, `1/4`, and so on, up to `1/log2 n`. The result would be an `A`; the denominator of the fraction would be `P`.

Since the computation of the power is in `double`s, you would need to try both `ceil` and `floor` of the result. Once you hit zero without finding a result, the algorithm could stop.

Comment: @xenteros You gave him the same exact solution :-)

Comment: @xenteros Regardless of when you stop, the approach is identical, as in "no difference whatsoever".

Answer (score 3):

This can also be solved this way.

```
public boolean isPower(int a) {
    if (a == 1) return true;
    for (int idx = 2; idx * idx <= a; idx ++) {
        double val = Math.log (a)/Math.log (idx);
        if ((val - (int) val) < 0.00000001) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why only 0.00000001 ?

Comment: Can you please explain the approach?

Answer (score 0):

1. we will check if a == 1 then it can be represented  as x ^ 0 hence
   true . for a > 1 we will check for either 2 or 3 or 4....a; we will
   divide p (p = a) if p % 2 or ,3 or ,4 or ....... if(p==1) means p is
   completely divisible by either 2, or 3, or 4 , ...... . means p
   (where p = a) can we written as x ^ y. hence return true.

---

```
 public boolean isPower(int a) {
       if(a==1) return true;
         for (int i = 2; i*i <= a; i++) {
              int p = a;
              while(p%i == 0){
                p/=i;
              }
              if(p == 1) return true;
         }
         return false;

  }
```

Comment: Please explain you solution briefly. Code-only answers are less useful and must be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Code based on @xenteros Answer and a successful submission .

```
public static int isPower(int A) {
        if(A == 1)
            return 1;
        double Ad = A ;
       for(int i =2;i<=(Math.log(Ad)/Math.log(2));i++)
       {
           double a = Math.pow(Ad,(double)1/i);
           if(Math.ceil(a) == Math.floor(a) || Math.ceil(a)-a <0.000000001)
                return 1;
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(test--)
{
    int input;
  cin>>input;

  if(input<=2)
  {cout<<"0"<<endl;
  break;}
  //cout<<m;
  int m=sqrt(input);
  int count=2;
  int flag=0;
while(count<=m+1)
{
    if(ceil(log2 (input)/log2 (count))== floor(log2 (input)/log2 (count)))
    {
       // cout<<"ghusa   "<<count<<"  "<<input;
        flag=1;
        cout<<"1";
        break;
    }
    count++;
}
if(flag==0)
{cout<<"0";

}
cout<<endl;  
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Please describe,  what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer. Additionally, the question is more than 2 years old and has an accepted answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
bool ans(long long int n)
{
    if(n==1)
        return true;
    else
    {
        for (long long int i = 2; i*i <= n; i++)
        {
            if(ceil(log2 (n)/log2 (i)) == floor(log2 (n)/log2 (i)))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Lets call the initial integer N.

First, you must get all the prime divisors of N.

If N has just 1 divisor, that it is in the form D^k, so it's true.

If it has more than 1 divisor, you should check if the gcd of the number of each divisor is different from 1 and is even.

For example:

```
12 = 2 * 2 * 3
not possible, GCD(2,1) = 1

24 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 3
not possible, GCD(3,1) = 1

36 = 2 * 2 * 3 * 3
possible,     GCD(2,2) = 2

144 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 3
possible,     GCD(4,2) = 2

120 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 5
not possible, GCD(1,1,3) = 1

216 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 * 3
not possible, GCD(3,3) = 3
```